# Populate a Dropdown Based on Selection of Another Dropdown in GXT

Tags: java, gwt, widget, gxt

I have a simple dropdown menu that when an item is selected from another dropdown, it should get populated by a set of values from the database based on the selection value of the second dropdown.

How can I do this in GXT 4?

Answer (score 1):

I've put together an example and posted it to a gist. Would this work for you?
https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/65ea27e16868c546ea7e